# Disable 404 Page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want user to type any URL, example:

```
mywebsite.com/helloworld
```

After, with `PHP` i'd like to take slug `helloworld`, and print it on the page.

By default Wordpress shows 404 page. My idea was to disable this page, but not sure if there's a better solution.

How i can achieve that?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by disabling a 404 page?  A custom 404 page is one thing, getting rid of a 404 entirely seems problematic.

Comment: The point of "404" is that the request was not found, be it a hardcoded page, or DB driven CMS like WP. Just showing what the user types in the URL on the page when there is no page found seems pointless.

Comment: WordPress has a specific 404 template (in any theme).  Why not leverage that to do what you need?

Comment: User should be able to go to a link on the site.
For example: `http://www.mywebsite.com/land/[any slug]`
I'll take slug, and make a search. If category is not found, i'll display some custom text, if found, display category. Wordpress returns 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`404` is one of many [HTTP Status Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and as such if you completely remove the page, you'll need to both disable it in WordPress and on your web server, eg Apache or Nginx. This is **not** advised as it will make browsers display legitimate 404's with uncontrollable/undesirable responses.

If your question is "the default/my templates 404 page is terrible and I want to change it" refer to the [Codex page on custom 404 page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Error_404_Page) or use one of the numerous plugins designed to template error pages.

I would also, personally, advise against directing error pages to a page of your choosing, eg your homepage. This does very little except confuse people wondering why example.com/helloworld goes to example.com. From a programmers perspective, it could add time to your development as you may find it harder to diagnose *why* you're getting redirected to your homepage rather than it coming up with `404` or `500` which each tell you different information.

Answer (score 4):

```
add_filter( 'pre_handle_404', function() {
    # you can do anything you want here but the easiest and safest is
    # wp_redirect( 'your url with query parameters from the failing 404 url' );
    # exit();
    return FALSE;
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

To go off of @magenta you can add conditions to this as well. This is what I did:

```
add_action( 'pre_handle_404', function() {
    global $wp_query;

    if(!$wp_query->found_posts){
        if($wp_query->query['post_type']=="clients"){
            wp_redirect( '/login' );
            exit;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
} );
```